# lookup configmap value in helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Say I have a configmap like this, and I want to get the value(12301) of version 123v1 in map_a, what is the correct way?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myconfig
  namespace: default
data:
  test.yml: |
    map_a:
      "123v1":
        "Version": 12301
        "Type": "abc"
......
```

Here is my attempts:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
data:
{{- $configmap := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" "default" "myconfig") }}
{{- if $configmap }}
  {{- $models := get $configmap.data "test.yml" }}
  version: {{ $models.map_a.123v1.Version }}
{{- end }}

$ helm template .
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: ""
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: /root/test-lookup


Error: parse error at (test-lookup/templates/config.yaml:9): ".123v"
helm.go:88: [debug] parse error at (test-lookup/templates/config.yaml:9): ".123v"
```

Answer (score 2):

The pipe symbol at the end of a line in YAML signifies that any indented text that follows should be interpreted as a multi-line scalar value. See the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688). This is also mentioned in the [helm doc |-](https://docs.helm.sh/zh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

`{{ $models }}` is a value behind a pipe symbol of `myconfig>data>test.yml`.

So, the value of the expression `{{ $models }}` is a string instead of a map. In other words, `{{ $models. map_a }}` is an illegal operation.

The real value of `{{ $models }}` is a multi-line string, the string content is:

```
map_a:
  "123v1":
    "Version": 12301
    "Type": "abc"
```

---

This can work here, of course the result is not what you want:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
data:
  {{- $configmap := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" "default" "myconfig") }}
  {{- if $configmap }}
  {{- $models := get $configmap.data "test.yml" }}
  version: {{ $models | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

output：

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  version: |
    map_a:
      "123v1":
        "Version": 12301
        "Type": "abc"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
...
```

---

So in order to achieve your purpose, you have to operate `{{ $models }}` in accordance with the method of operating strings.

config.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config
data:
  {{- $configmap := (lookup "v1" "ConfigMap" "default" "myconfig") }}
  {{- if $configmap }}
  {{- $models := get $configmap.data "test.yml" }}
  {{- range ( split "\n" $models) }}
  {{- if ( contains "Version" .) }}
  version: {{ (split ":" .)._1 | trim | quote }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

output:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  version: "12301"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
...
```

Comment: Also, don't forget that lookup is NOT called during a template operation, as per the helm docs

Comment: when is it called then? @Darren I really can't figure it out

Comment: From the [Helm docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function): "To test lookup against a running cluster, helm template|install|upgrade|delete|rollback --dry-run=server should be used instead to allow cluster connection."

Comment: However, that doesn't seem to work ‍♀️

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that Helm is not supposed to contact the Kubernetes API Server during a helm template or a helm install|upgrade|delete|rollback --dry-run, so the lookup function will return an empty list (i.e. dict) in such a case.